# Mantis Related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am searching for the right website where I can ask Mantis bug tracker related questions? Can anybody suggest the appropriate site? It is a bug tracker application related query.

This is a specific question related with Mantis bug tracker.

Comment: Stack Overflow has 165 questions tagged [mantis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mantis).

Comment: How on earth is it duplicate when I am asking a specific question and the question @gnat is referring is a generic one?

Comment: Mantis is similar [trac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trac) or [jira](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira) and is in that sense a tool used by developers and as long as it is a specific problem with a feature and not an open ended discussion StackOverflow would be the correct choise, as indicated by the dupe.